# Total profit and loss calculation from option trading with options events with the Robinhood API data

Tags: javascript, calculation, stock, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm writing an Chrome extension to calculate total profit and loss from Robinhood trading history.

Found out that total profit/loss calculation for options trading is more complicated than what I expected when counting options events such as expiration, exercise, and assignment.

I tried to think through all possible scenarios and came up with the formula that I think it will work but wanted to get some other eyes on it to see if I'm missing anything or doing it completely wrong.

```
// Option trading Profit / Loss occurrence

// Buy to open call options > Betting on Bullish
//    - TotalPL = (selling/expried premium * quantity) - (buying premium * quantity)
//    - Exercise (underlying_price * (quantity * 100)) - (strike_price * (quantity * 100))



// Sell to open call options > Betting on Bearish
//    - TotalPL = (buying premium * quantity) - (selling/expried premium * quantity)
//    - Assignment (strike_price * (quantity * 100)) - (underlying_price * (quantity * 100))
//
//    Example: Sell 2 of SPY $200 2023/01/06 call options at $10 premium (with the 200 shares of SPY as a collateral)
//    Senario 1) selling options before expiration
//      TotalPL = ($10 * 2) - (current premium at the time of selling * 2)
//    Senario 2) option expired in the money
//      TotalPL = ($10 * 2) - (0 * 2) >> current premium at the time of selling is $0. You keep all the credit. It is the same as senario 1.
//    Senario 3) option expired out of the money. SPY ended at $250 on 2023/01/06
//      TotalPL = ($200 * 200) - ($250 * 200)



// Buy to open put options > Betting on Bearish
//    - TotalPL = (selling/expried premium * quantity) - (buying premium * quantity)
//    - Exercise (strike_price * (quantity * 100)) - (underlying_price * (quantity * 100))



// Sell to open put options > Betting on Bullish
//    - TotalPL = (buying premium * quantity) - (selling/expried premium * quantity)
//    - Assignment (underlying_price * (quantity * 100)) - (strike_price * (quantity * 100))
```